# Vertically centering divs within div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically  center the Post Title, Byline and comments in the parent div.

Everything I've done only puts way too much space between the lines or centers only horizontally. Appreciate any guidance.

```html
<div class="container main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
      <div id="latest" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="SeeMore">
          <p class="play">
            See More
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
          <h3 class="latest-title"> post title </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
          <h6 class="byline"> Author: Sheila Date:</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 comments">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They look pretty aligned to me.

Comment: I want them to be in the middle of the box though.

Comment: In that case, we need to see the rest of the CSS. By doing it like this, we need to change a lot of stuff around, so please post your CSS.

Comment: Please add your code here rather than just posting a link to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **flex**

```
.inner {
  text-align: center;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a quick fix for aligning vertically and being in center for the code you have provided

```
<div class="container main" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="row" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; text-align: left;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
          <div id="latest" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="SeeMore">
              <p class="play">
                See More
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer" style="text-align: left;">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
              <h3 class="latest-title"> post title </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
              <h6 class="byline"> Author: Sheila Date:</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 comments">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```